# configure linux out streams

Tags: linux, configuration, floating-point

There is an issue in Linux, that it has `0` and `-0`.
This is because of Floating points, etc.
I want to always ignore the `-` before the `0`.

Is there a way to configure the 'out stream' (to a file) or the working IDE/editor?

thank you

Comment: Sorry, you are not giving us enough info to help you. What produces your stream? A bash script?

Comment: i have a very basic code. i am using c++ , iostream. i am writing to files.
i want that any time that it is going to print -0 , it will print 0.
is there a way to change the definitions/configuration?

Comment: Minus zero is a feature of IEEE754-style FP, if you don't like it, use `fabs(3)`.

Comment: that is an option, but then every time i write a value to a file, or print it i have to use that, i  need a more global solution, you know what i  mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, you may be able to create your own stream formatter specialization:

Something like

```
class my_ostream : public std::ostream {
public:
  my_ostream& operator<<( float f ) {
     std::ostrstream oss;
     oss << f;
     if( oss.str() == "-0" ) f = fabs(f);
     *this->std::ostream << f;
     return *this;
  }
};
```

You probably need to copy formatting from *this to the ostringstream.

Note that I have created a wrapper type. You *might* be able simply to overload a specialization for

```
std::ostream& operator(<< std::ostream& os, float f )
```

and similarly for doubles, and other float types.